# How to make icon of app on desktop? Problems with WebView

Tags: android

In my app I have one activity with WebView.

When I push Home button and then click on icon my app -- web page do not reload - it is good.
But in code I create icon manually:

```
private void createIcon(int iconId){
        final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        ComponentName name = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), ".FullScreenBrowserActivity");
        shortcutIntent.setComponent(name);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Fulscreen Browser");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, iconId));

        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

When I click this icon - app starts new copy of themselfs and webpage starts loading.

How to make new icon on desktop manual(after install) and when click on icon - webpage in WebView do no reloading?

Thanks!